# TrailRenderer start point on click

Tags: unity-game-engine

I followed Brackeys tutorial on how to create a Fruit Ninja Replica ([youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3g5_8sE18tQ&t=1619s)).
When creating the blade, though, the behaviour I got wasn't exactly the same.

## Expected behaviour

[image]

## Actual behaviour

[image]

The difference is that in the *Actual behaviour*, the trail starts where it stopped the last time it was shown. The code responsible for this is exactly the same as the video:

```cs
public class BladeController : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool isCutting = false;
    public GameObject bladeTrailPrefab;
    GameObject currentBlade;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            StartCutting();
        } else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
            StopCutting();
        }

        if (isCutting) {
            UpdateCut();
        }
    }

    void UpdateCut()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }

    void StartCutting()
    {
        isCutting = true;
        this.currentBlade = Instantiate(bladeTrailPrefab, transform);
    }

    void StopCutting()
    {
        isCutting = false;
        Destroy(currentBlade, 1f);
    }
}
```

After understanding the code, I thought the problem was that I instantiated the bladeTrail before actually moving the Blade to the new position, but tried moving the `Instantiate` method to `UpdateCut` after changing the position and only if `this.currentBlade == null`.

I've search a lot about this, and even found some [other posts](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1536645/trail-renderer-tracking-problem.html) with the same problem but no answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seams the Instantiate is using the last mouse position to instiantiate the prefab.

Maybe use:

```java
Instantiate(bladeTrailPrefab, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Quaternion.identity)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. In fact, the trail disappears doing so (I guess it's because of a Z axis problem?) i don't know

Comment: What if you cache the position of the onclick and instantiate there?

Comment: Did you end up solving it?

Comment: Hi! I had no luck, and didn't find help. Please, if you find a workaround let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem following the tutorial as well.

It's a few years later but for those of you who hit this page, I found a solution for me that while isn't fantastic, it's better than having the streaks shown in the post.

Before instantiating the trail vfx, make sure to wait until fixed update is called after you set the position of the parent transform.

I did this with a Coroutine like so:

```html
private IEnumerator StartCutting()
{
    // When we begin cutting, move the blade object to the input position
    m_isCutting = true;
    m_previousPosition = m_camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    m_rigidBody.position = m_previousPosition;

    // Then for positions to be updated so that the vfx doesn't get confused
    yield return m_waitForFixedUpdate; // new WaitForFixedUpdate(); <-- cache this

    // Instantiate the trail at this new position
    m_currentTrail = Instantiate(m_trailPrefab, m_rigidBody.transform);
    m_collider.enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. fixed it by using

```
var m=Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
transform.position=new Vector3(m.x,m.y,transform.position.z);
```

instead of

```
rb.position=Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
```